# Azsure Worker Role reading from Queue

Tags: azure-web-roles, servicebus

I've implemented a Web role that writes to a queue. This is working fine. Then I developed a Worker role to read from the queue. When I run it in debug mode from my local machine it reads the messages from the queue fine,  but when i deploy the Worker role it dos'nt seem to be reading the queue as the message eventually end up in the dead letter queue. Anyone know what could be causing this behavior? Below are some bit that might be key in figuring this thing out

```
queueClient = QueueClient.Create(queueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
var queueDescription = new QueueDescription(QueueName)
   {
       RequiresSession = false,
       DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
       EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration = true,
       MaxDeliveryCount = 20
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

Increase the QueueDescription.DefaultmessageTimeToLive to ~10 mins.

This property dictates how much time a message should live in the Queue - before being processed (Message.Complete() is called). If it remains in the queue for more than 2 mins - it will be automatically moved to DeadLetterQueue (as you had Set EnableDeadLetteringOnMsgExp to true).

TTL is useful in these messaging scenarios

- if a message is not being processed after N mins after it arrived -then it might not be useful to process it any more
- if the message was attempted to process many times and was never completed (Reciever - msg.Complete()) - this might be needing special processing

So - to be safe have a bit higher value of DefaultMsgTTL.

Hope it Helps!
Sree